# Unable to Import Values into SQL Server Database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf

I've been attempting to add a an entry into an existing table I have. When ever I attempt to add values (I used 4, name, desc as subholder values to test adding items to a table), it does not appear to import/add properly. I've checked if the connection establishes properly, check if the method is being called, and nothing is changed. I receive no errors in output or error list. The only significant thing I've been able to discover is if I have an existing view of the table data and attempt to refresh it, I get a "This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL server version or an unsupported database compatibility." error. If I close the view and reopen it through server explorer, refreshing acts normally but no changes have occurred.

//Code Formating is weird due to copy pasting

```
    public static SqlConnection Get_DB_Connection()
    {
         string cn_String = Properties.Settings.Default.birdCategoriesConnectionString;
         SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_String);
         if (cn_connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) cn_connection.Open();
         return cn_connection;
    }
    
    public static void AddDataValues()
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection connection = Get_DB_Connection(); //Opens new SqlConnection
            string Query = "INSERT dbo.DivisionTable (Id,Name,Description) VALUES (4,'Name','Desc')"; 
            //test Values 4|name|desc
            SqlCommand classCommand = new SqlCommand(Query, connection);
            classCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Debug.WriteLine("Saved");
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
             Close_DB_Connection();
        }
    }

    public static void Close_DB_Connection()
    {
        string cn_String = Properties.Settings.Default.birdCategoriesConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cn_connection = new SqlConnection(cn_String);
    
        if (cn_connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
            cn_connection.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Well it should be thrown as a `SqlException`, but the SQL statement should be `"INSERT INTO ..."`

Comment: Is something calling `AddDataValues` that could be swallowing the exception? And how does `Close_DB_Connection` know what connection to close since you don't pass it one?

Comment: @DStanley "INTO" is an optional part of an INSERT statement.

Comment: I would suggest wrapping your command and connection objects in a USING statement. Then you don't need the try/catch here since you are just throwing the exception back anyway. The USING statement will properly close and dispose your object inheriting IDiposable.

Comment: Something is not quite right here. You talk about a view, but you also talk about a table. And then the error message you have is completely unrelated to the code you posted.

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, to clarify, the main issue I'm having is that I can add values to a table I have. I only mentioned the error message and view because that's the only thing displaying any sort of error message and I am unsure if it was relevant or not so I added it just in case.

Comment: So you have a view that selects from this table and that view throws an exception after you add new rows to the table? Something here just doesn't add up. I think you might need to step back from the problem a little bit. The explanation here is not making sense. Also providing table structures and such would probably help.

Comment: What is your connection string? Also, there are quite a few issues in the above code: Do not cache the connection object, create when you need it and put it in a `using`. Do not `throw ex;` as it will wipe the stack trace, instead just `throw;` or if you aren't handling an exception don't catch it at all.